# Skybrud social Log in via Facebook?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I'm usinng [skybrud social](http://social.skybrud.dk/) to allow users to log into my site via Facebook, but am having a problem.

For some reason, the response never contains anything other than the Name and Id of the user... everything else is null.

```
 var url = client.GetAuthorizationUrl(state, "public_profile", "email");

var service = FacebookService.CreateFromAccessToken(userAccessToken);
FacebookMeResponse user = service.Methods.Me();
```

Has anyone experienced this before? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has multiple versions of their Graph API. In the most recent version (2.4), less fields are returned by default, and you instead have to tell the API to return the fields that you need. What version of the API you're using depends on the time you registered your app with Facebook.

Based on your code, it seems that you're using an older version of Skybrud.Social. If you update to the most recent version (0.9.4.1), you can do something like this:

```
// Declare the options for the call to the API
FacebookGetUserOptions options = new FacebookGetUserOptions("me") {
    Fields = "name,email,gender"
};

// Make the call to the API
FacebookUserResponse response = service.Users.GetUser(options);
```

Hope this answers your questions ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've since got it working - I updated a while back but have forgotten about the question. Anyways, thanks and what you have suggested is correct.